# Creating a CSS hover style that doesn't jump

Tags: html, css

I made a mobile responsive hamburger menu to horizontal nav bar, but I'm having trouble making a hover style for the links on the horizontal nav bar that don't make them jump. If you look at my Codpen you'll see the general style I want on those links on hover, but I want that highlight to be larger around the wording. When I've tried to do this the links end up jumping on hover. The other thing is that I can't get the top highlight much bigger... it's like it's cut off with some other property. This is the first menu like this I've made (I'm fairly new) so I played around with a lot of different CSS properties and values to get things to look perfect upon first glance and I'm sure some CSS isn't right, I just don't know what or where. I pasted the code below with everything inline but definitely check out the codpen because that's more accurate to how it looks on my computer. Thanks for your help!

http://codepen.io/sshine2/pen/VbjGaE

EDIT: I edited the code in Codepen to show how the top of the highlight gets cut off and the link jumps when the highlight is the size I want it to be.

SECOND EDIT: Fixed the top being cut off myself. Changed where the entire menu was displayed.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html lang="en">

 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">

 <style>
body {
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: #ffffff;
 background-color: black;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }

header {
 width: 100%;
 background: #ffffff;
 position: fixed;
 height: 4em;
 line-height: 4em;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 1em;
 border-bottom: .1em solid #dddddd;
  }
h2 {
 font-size: 2.1em;
  }
p {
 font-size: 10em;
 color: white;
 padding-top: 1em;
  }

@media only screen and (min-width: 319px) {

 .menu {
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 3.3em;
    color: black;
  }

  .menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    border-top: #dddddd 1px solid;
  }   

  .menu li {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
    border-bottom: #dddddd 1px solid;
  }

  .menu li:hover {
    display: block;
    background: #585858;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
      cursor: crosshair;
  }

  .menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    color: black;
  }

  .menu ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }

  .menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
  }

  #nav-icon4 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 25px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -47px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: cell;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background: darkred;
    border-radius: 7px;
    opacity: 2;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 20px;
     -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }

  #nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 0;
    left: 6px;
  }

  #nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(2) {
    width: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  #nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 25px;
    left: 6px;
  }   
  }


@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {   
     h2 {
      z-index: 1000000;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      }

        p {
            font-size: 20em;
            color: white;
            padding-top: 1em;
  }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
  }

  li {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.menu {
    display: block!important;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: .9em;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }
.menu ul {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    }
.menu li {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    }
 .menu li:hover {
    cursor: crosshair;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: .4em;
    padding-right: 0em;
    padding-left: 0em;
   }

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#nav-icon4 {
    display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 922px) {
    li {
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 18px;

    }
.menu {
    padding-right: 1px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (min-width : 1400px) {
    header {
       height: 5em;
      line-height: 5em;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 2.6em;    
    }
    li {
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    }
    .menu {
        padding-right: 1px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
}

    </style>

 <title>hamburgers</title>
 </head>

 <body>
     <header>

      <span>Shine Design</span>
      <div id="nav-icon4">
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
      </div>

     </header>

     <div class="menu">
      <ul>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK ONE</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK TWO</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK THREE</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK FOUR</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK FIVE</li>
       </a>
      </ul>
     </div>

   </body>

 <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");</script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#nav-icon4').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
      });
    });
    </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: your html is invalid. a `ul`'s direct children should be `li`, not `a`

Comment: I don't see anything jumping.

Comment: Fixed that, thank you.  -- The links aren't jumping now but if I make the highlight around the links larger, which is what I want, then they jump. So for instance right now this is the code: 
        .menu li:hover {
         padding-top: 1em;
         padding-bottom: .4em;
         padding-right: 0em;
         padding-left: 0em;
          }
But I want it to be 1em around each side.

Comment: I just changed it so you can see what I mean. The top is cut off and now they jump.

Comment: Instead of having us guess however you want the highlight around the links to be larger, put that highlight in the code in your post and let us fix the jumpy hover stuff.

Comment: Good call. I edited it. Still getting the hang of all this. Thanks.

Comment: Don't change padding on hover... http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/OmXeMZ what do you expect to happen to the element if you change the padding when you hover and you don't want it to shift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jumping issue is because you add padding on hover which isn't there before.

Before your media queries define the padding ones:

```
.menu li {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

Then remove the defined paddings for `.menu li` in your min 768px query.,

[code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNKQGK)

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Now just can't figure out why the top is getting cut off when I hover. Would you mind looking at the CSS again? I've edited it.

Comment: Nevermind I got it. You pointed me in the right direction though. Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Comment: you're welcome, so you solved the cutted top issue? just struggled to get it work. Seems like the menu padding cuts the ```li```s. could solve it easily with fixed heights for menu, tabs  etc.. but never did something like this in the way you're doing it.  How did you solve it?

Comment: You've probably never done something the way I'm doing it because of how new I am! lol I have a tendency to write new CSS to force things in place instead of editing existing properties. It's something I need to work on. Needless to say that's what happened with the top being cut off. To fix it I deleted all padding on .menu and just added margins. Then I realized that was all the CSS I needed. So I had put padding where it was unnecessary.  I put the finished version in the same codepen if you wanna check it out! It still may not be to standard but it's much better than before and it works!